# how can I filter on the second element in a tuple of tuples?

Tags: python, django, filter, country

In my model I have a field:

```
   country = models.CharField(_('Country'), max_length=2, choices=COUNTRIES)
```

Where COUNTRIES is a tuple of tuples like this:

```
COUNTRIES = (
    ('AF', _('Afghanistan')),
```

... and so on

Now I want to filter an instance of that model, by the country name.

This:

```
   i = MyModel.objects.filter(country__iexact=query)
```

only lets me filter by the country code.

How can I filter by country name?

Comment: I think you're missing a bit of code there.  Can you show me where query gets defined?

Comment: In
q = request.GET['q'].lower()
but that's irrelevant, I could as well hardcode a string in the example, like:

   i = MyModel.objects.filter(country__iexact='Afganistan')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot filter directly by the country name (the `choices` are only used in the UI, not in the database).

If you get the full name as an input, lookup the code in the `COUNTRIES` tuple-of-tuples. For example:

```
# ... initialize a lookup dictionary
country_to_id_dict = dict((t[1], t[0]) for t in COUNTRIES)

# ... use the dictionary in the query
i = MyModel.objects.filter(country__exact=country_to_id_dict[query])
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this, but I get a Exception Type: KeyError with the country_to_id_dict looking somehow like this:

{<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1d0f7d0>: 'AF', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1d0f8d0>: 'AL', 

... and so on.

Maybe its because the second element in each tuple is a translatable text, because:

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

Comment: OK, a minor modification of country_to_dict worked:

country_to_id_dict = dict((t[1][:], t[0]) for t in COUNTRIES)

Thanks.

Even better to maek this case insensitive (the query is folded to lowercase elsewhere):

country_to_id_dict = dict((t[1][:].lower(), t[0]) for t in COUNTRIES)